# Arba'a Ushloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 134th day from Rosh Hashanna is Tu Bishvat, if either Heshvan or Kislev is Haser (has only 29 days), and the other one is Male (has 30 days)
(I hope it's ok that I'm using Tu Bishvat as an  answe to 133, 134, and b"h 135 Mi Yodeya....)

Comment: I'm out of upvotes for the day, B"H. You and GG will get your upvotes in about six hours.

Comment: Re: reuse - There's plenty of precedence for this. I'd say that 134 is the most natural of these, but in general in this region of the universe of numbers, beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score -1):

Gematrias from the Parsha

מה החלום

לנחמו